# Button to easily copy code snippets

Tags: feature-request, design, code

There should be a little icon in the corner of each code snippet which when clicked, copies the entire code snippet to the clipboard.

```
Test snippet
```

Currently, there is no easy way to copy this snippet, other than to select it manually, right click, and click copy.

Comment: "The question should therefore be rather why it wasn't implemented since 2009 when the feature was requested? I doubt it's the complexity of implementation. Maybe it just went off the radar and then this reminder is very valuable." *Three years later....*

Comment: @Draco18s, Q3 2019 and there is still no copy button.